# Invalid Signature in Future method

Tags: future

When a user get inserted, I have @future method call which updates Contact and call another future method.

Trigger Code

```
UserTriggerUtility_HDS.InsertUserSendToIDM(Trigger.New[0].userType,Trigger.New[0].ContactId);
```

Function Call

```
@Future    
public static void InsertUserSendToIDM (string Usertype,Id ConId){
       if (Usertype = 'PowerPartner' && ConId <> Null){
            Contact oCon = new Contact (Id = ConId,Send_TO_IDM_HDS__c = true);
           update oCon;
        } 

   }
```

Why am I getting "Method does not exist or incorrect signature" error here?

Comment: can you post your complete trigger code and the UserTriggerUtility_HDS class..

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that your InsertUserSendToIDM method has not been saved to the server because of errors. The method has errors in it that would prevent it from saving, because you are using an assignment operator instead of an equality operator ( = vs ==). The if statement should read:

```
if (Usertype == 'PowerPartner' && ConId <> null)
```

If that class was unable to save because of the error, then your trigger will throw a 'method does not exist' error because the method really doesn't exist yet on the server.

Comment: You *can* use an assignment operator in an if-statement, but the result of the assignment still needs a boolean result. For example, you can write `while(iter.hasNext() && (item = iter.next()) != null)`, just as you can in older languages such as C, although I'd argue against that format in all but the most trivial cases.